# SIZEOF_UNSIGNED_CHAR header file or package in ubuntu(linux)?

Tags: c, linux, header-files

I use ubuntu 20.04, when I compile an header file of code，I have error:

```
../../../../../../src/tool/omniidl/cxx/cccp/config.h:80:23: error: ‘SIZEOF_UNSIGNED_CHAR’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   80 | #define BITS_PER_UNIT SIZEOF_UNSIGNED_CHAR
```

I just want to know which header file or which Linux package contains SIZEOF_UNSIGNED_CHAR defined?

Comment: Not sure is this is a standard macro, but usually it's defined to be `1`.

Comment: I doubt you'll find that in any Linux package - the size of all `char` types in C is ***always*** one by definition, so such a macro definition is entirely unecessary.  You need to find out what whatever you're compiling is dependent upon.

Comment: It seems to be a product of a configure script in that specific software package (omniORB). You should follow the instructions in the package's documentation.

Comment: Looks like a Microsoft type. What are you trying to compile?

Answer (score 0):

It's 1 as it's the smallest unit you can use. If you prefer not to write `#define ... 1` you can use `sizeof`.

I recommend you to read [this](http://scc-forge.lancaster.ac.uk/open/char/types/byte), it's an interesting page.